# How to create PDF documentation with Sphinx in Windows

Tags: windows, pdf, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx to create documentation for my Python project in Windows. I need to generate PDF documentation. I found many explanation how to do this in Linux, but no good explanation how to do this in Windows. As far as i understand I need to create Latex format with Sphinx, and than use Texworks to convert Latex to PDF. Can someone provide step by step explanation how can I do this, assuming I created documentation in Latex format and installed Texworks?

Comment: "*assuming I created documentation in Latex format*". So you have managed to get LaTeX output from Sphinx?

Comment: @mzjn Yes, i got latex output

Comment: OK, then perhaps this question should be asked at http://tex.stackexchange.com instead. There is a Texworks tag: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texworks.

Comment: @mzjn Ok. I will tray at tex.stackexchange.com Thank you. But I thought it is some automatic way to do this from Sphinx without actually working with Texworks

Comment: You'll need *some* LaTeX distribution in order to generate PDFs from LaTeX sources. I don't know anything about Texworks, sorry.

Answer (score 20):

Install MiKTeX (< 200mb)

```
wget -nv -N http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/setup/miktex-portable-2.9.4757.exe
7z.exe x -y miktex-portable-2.9.4757.exe -o"miktex"
```

Add the bin directory to your path

```
SET Path=%Path%;%CD%\miktex\miktex\bin
```

Run Sphinx's "make.bat" to generate the .tex file.

```
SET SPHINXOPTS=-W -E
make.bat latex
```

Invoke MiKTeX's pdflatex:

```
cd build/latex
pdflatex.exe YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.tex
```

The resultant PDF will be in your build/latex directory

Answer (score 5):

Install the *full* [tex live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) distribution, it will install latex, PDF backends and texworks.  Yes it is much, yes, it will dl and install for a fat hour depending on your pipe. But it will be sub gig total, and harddisks are large nowadays.

From what I see, ***Texworks*** is just a simple LaTeX editor with some build functionality and latex syntax highlighting. It is not really needed for just compiling (you could use notepad)

Then it should be a matter of simply putting the tex live binary directory i the path and  doing

```
    pdflatex <yourlatexdocument.tex>
```

on the cmdline, at least that is what I do with the latex output of our own documentation generating tool

Answer (score -1):

As you have figured out: use Sphinx to generate LaTeX source, and then run it through a LaTex compiler to produce your PDF.

Instead of troubling yourself with installing LaTeX (which can be daunting) and getting an editor set up, I suggest that you use one of the on-line LaTeX services. You then only have to create a project in ShareLaTeX or Overleaf, for example (which are in the process of merging), upload the contents of the Sphinx build\latex directory, compile on-line, and download the finished PDF.

This works reasonably well, but since the output targets are very different (HTML vs a formal document), you may have to fiddle with the reST to get things the way you like it.