# Tool to generate CHM and PDF documentation from Markdown on Windows

Tags: pdf, markdown, python-sphinx, chm

Is there a tool that generates both PDF and CHM documentation from Markdown (or similar, such as RST) on Windows.

We are currently using [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/), but have been unable to get the PDF generation working on Windows ([this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155509/how-to-create-pdf-documentation-with-sphinx-in-windows) has the same issue). It's a pain to have to generate the CHM on Windows and the PDF version on Linux (and I do need to generate both versions).

Is there an alternative tool (free or inexpensive commercial) that could do this task?

The source format *must* be in a plain-text-like format for version control, of which Markdown and RST are examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fulfil this need using [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) after all. I used [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) to generate the PDF on Windows.

Install MiKTeX (< 200mb)

```
wget -nv -N http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/setup/miktex-portable-2.9.4757.exe
7z.exe x -y miktex-portable-2.9.4757.exe -o"miktex"
```

Add the bin directory to your path

```
SET Path=%Path%;%CD%\miktex\miktex\bin
```

Run Sphinx's "make.bat" to generate the .tex file.

```
SET SPHINXOPTS=-W -E
make.bat latex
```

Invoke MiKTeX's pdflatex:

```
cd build/latex
pdflatex.exe YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.tex
```

The resultant PDF will be in your build/latex directory

Comment: ...anything new about the CHM part?

Answer (score 5):

The [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org) distribution holds a CHM compiler called **chmcmd**. Some people with documentation tools report success with it (like the [Preshrunk-cotton python package](http://code.google.com/p/preshrunk-cotton))

Some Linux distros also pack the chm compiler independently from the main FPC distribution. (since it only is a 700k binary without dependencies).

On Windows you can use the same (the windows version of chmcmd), or Microsoft Help Workshop, the default CHM generator from MS.

That's the CHM compiler part, now the input:

A *CHM project* before compilation is basically **just html** with a couple of XML indexes (TOC and master keyword based index) and a project file that is an INI file.

Usually the HTML generator backend of a documentation tool is tweaked to generate it as a special case. From what I read in your "this guy" link, sphinx can do that.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. It doesn't fulfil my needs, but there's lots of great ideas here.

Comment: I generate CHM and PDF on both platforms so also need a laTEX on both. A few years ago, on windowsI migrated from "miktex" to "texlive", so that I have the same TeX distro on Linux and Windows.